# React hook call inside if (condition)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Is it wrong to use a React hook call inside a condition?

I know it's wrong to use it **inside a conditional block**, 'cause it will mess with the order of the calls, and the linter warns me about it.

```
import {useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';

if (condition) {
  useRouteMatch("/blog/:slug");   //  <---- THIS IS WRONG AND IT BREAKS HOOK's RULES
}
```

**But this does not trigger any warnings and it seems to work fine:**

```
import {useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';

if (useRouteMatch("/blog/:slug")) {
  console.log("something");
}
```

That does not trigger any warnings and it runs fine. I know that most of the times it won't make sense to call the hook inside the `condition`, but in this case it does, 'cause this is basically a helper function that is probably aware of some `Context`.

**QUESTION**

Is it breaking any hook's rule? Is it ok to do it? Does being inside a `if (condition)` counts as being on top-level?

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't if you need it's state or do some operation based on the state you should probably use a useEffect. Can you paste the exact code and the desired behaviour?

Comment: there seems to be an unfortunate use of the word `condition` between https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else (where it describes the expression) and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html (where it describes any statement that may or may not execute) Note: there is no definition of "condition" in the standard 

Comment: @Aprillion that is what got me confused, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd code snippet follows the rules of hooks. It will always call the hook the exact same number of times. Personally, i would pull it before the if statement just to make it clearer, but that's not strictly necessary.

```
const match = useRouteMatch("/blog/:slug");
if (match) {
  console.log("something");
}
```

Comment: faster @ typing than I am!

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code does not violate the rules of hook as the hook will always run in the same order. The hook is not written inside the `if` condition, instead based on return value of `useRouteMatch` we are executing the code inside the `if` condition`

```
import {useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';

if (useRouteMatch("/blog/:slug")) {
  console.log("something");
}
```

This code is equivalent to:

```
import {useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';

const isMatch = useRouteMatch("/blog/:slug");

if (isMatch) {
  console.log("something");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What may be best and more clear would be to assign the hook to a variable.

```
const routeMatch = useRouteMatch("/blog/:slug");

if (routeMatch) {
   // do something
}
```